# Use Facebook og meta tags to include image with link

Tags: facebook, metadata, meta-tags

This may look like a duplicate question but when I asked this along with a similar question I had it deleted and was told to ask a new question.

I'm trying to get Facebook to show an image when I link to my site. There seems to be a way to get it to use an image of your choice rather than taking it from the page but it cannot get it to work. 
The code I'm using is below:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="My Title">
<meta property="og:type" content="company">
<meta property="og:url" content="My URL">
<meta property="og:image" content="My Path/images/My Image.jpg">
<meta property="og:description" content="My Description">
```

The path for the image is fine. If I copy into the address bar it shows but every time I do this is just taking the image from the page.
I'm guessing there is something really obvious that I'm missing. Would somebody be able to point it out?

Comment: Use the debug tool to check your URL: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ enter your URL and click "Fetch new scrape information" to refresh all meta data.

Comment: I did that and it told me there were tags in the body. I had a look at what Facebook sees and got this
'code'<html><body>
<p>&iuml;&raquo;&iquest;

</p>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta property="og:image:url" content="default.jpg">

Somehow it's putting some code and it seem Facebook doesn't see the head tag.
When the view the source it looks okay,